# Formula for changing cell color depending on data in 4 cells

Tags: excel-formula

I would like a cell to change color if the value entered is identical to a value entered in that same column elsewhere AND the values in another column also match.

> Ex: One employee cannot obtain the same prize twice. In column D, we
>   put the employee number. In column G, we place the prize product
>   number.

I want it so that if the employee number and product number are entered a second time, that the prize product number cell be highlighted in yellow (which would mean the employee has already received this prize).

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is actually about **Conditional Formatting** and of course it needs to incorporate Excel Formula.

I have added a helper column called **Check** to help explaining my logic, but you do not have to insert such column in your actual worksheet.

The formula in cell H2 (see below picture) is: `{=SUM(--($D2&$G2=Employee_No&Prize_No))>1}`

It is an **ARRAY FORMULA** so you need to press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` upon finishing the formula.

This formula will find out if an employee has received the same prize more than once, if so it will return **TRUE**.

If you know how to use formula in Conditional Formatting, then it is just a matter of copying and paste the formula to Conditional Formatting section for the right range of cells.

Please see below steps:
[image: Conditional Formatting]

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)